# Anaconda/Rstudio displays at low resolution on mac retina screen

Tags: rstudio, anaconda

The Rstudio installation contained in Anaconda 4.3.1 is displayed at low resolution on my macbook with retina screen.

Other anaconda apps, but also the standalone version of Rstudio look fine.

Any ideas on how this can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a legacy from the days of us supporting macOS 10.7.

Open your `RStudio.app/Contents/Info.plist` file and add:

`<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key><true/>`

.. near the end, just before the `</dict>`

After that you may need to refresh macOS's cached information after editing and before relaunching.

From Terminal:

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -v -f ${CONDA_PREFIX}/Applications/RStudio.app

I have added it to the code so next time I rebuild it this doesn't get missed.

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I tried all possibilities (as there are several dictionaries in the plist file. But it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. My provisional solution is to run RStudio from the command line. First activate the desired workspace, then run RStudio:

```
source activate workspace-name
RStudio
```